# How to run multiple AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have 2 spinner,
each spinner's data loaded from database using AsyncTask

i call the AsyncTasks using this

```
new PopulateSpinnerA().execute();
```

it works if i only call one AsyncTask for one Spinner

BUT!

i have 2 Spinners, so i call the AsyncTask for each Spinner like this

```
new PopulateSpinnerA().execute(); // for Spinner A
new PopulateSpinnerB().execute(); // for Spinner B
```

I run it and my app force close

solution?

**UPDATE!**

i get inspiration from someone below who answer with true and false

im using a boolean (playing with true and false) to make my two spinners generated

first i make a boolean variable

```
Boolean SPN = false;
```

then i make a function to check the boolean and put it on onCreate() function

```
private void cek(){
        if(!SPN){
            new populateSpinnerA().execute();
        }
        if(SPN){
            new populateSpinnerB().execute();
        }
    }
```

on populateSpinnerA() i just put this 2 lines to run the second spinner's AsyncTask

```
SPN = true;
cek();
```

and

BOOM!

it's done :D

Comment: show the error message that you are getting in the Logcat

Comment: i dont think it need to review stack trace as two spinner can run on same time.

Comment: to add on your approach above, you dont really need tow objects like populateSpinnerA and populateSpinnerB. Any one will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not have two spinner at a time. Need to use any trick in this case,

1. Use only one spinner.
2. Start the spinner while initiating first spinner.
3. Use one common flag set on PostExecute.
4. Before step#3, on postExecute of both AsyncTask check the flag is already set, if yes just cancel the spinner.

Refer below pseudo code.

```
postExecute(){
      If(taskCompletedFlag == true){
            //Code to cancel the spinner.
            taskCompletedFlag = false;
      }else{
            taskCompledtedFlag = true;
      }
}
```

P.S. - In case you are not aware which AsyncTask will initiate first, you can use same mechanism over there.

Comment: i get inspiration from this answer :D